# Dagger 2 - modules added to graph per activity vs in application.java

Tags: android, performance, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Is it wise to to add modules to the Object graph in application.java file ? or should they 
only be added per activity?

For example, in an activity class imagine we already had a vehicle module but it was not added to the object graph. We then c
could do the following in onCreate:

```
VehicleComponent vehicleComponent = DaggerVehicleComponent.builder().vehicleModule(new VehicleModule()).build();
```

this would then add the vehicle module to the graph and then we could use the `@inject` annotation on a variable called vehicle for example.

this is in contrast to doing the same call in the application.java file.  Isn't the former better on memory ?

Comment: I think that's a valid approach, but what i like to do is build the graph in one place, and if is necessary use Lazy Injections.

Comment: yah im just wondering when you build the graph in one place isn't it more memory issues ?

Comment: I've never compared the two approaches usin MAT or other memory analyzer, and haven't read about a comparison either, so really i don't know, but i've never had memory issues by building the graph in one place. Even one app with my own memory leaks never crashed. If is for an important project you should make time and compare and choose what suits better for your app.